# json.loads only works for nonunicode JSON

Tags: python, json

I have some json displayed below.

```
{  
   u'application':{  
      u'platform':u'iPhone',
      u'locale':u'en_US',
      u'server':{  
         u'test':False
      },
      u'os_version':u'8.1',
      u'carrier':u'unknown',
      u'device':u'iPhone Simulator',
      u'app_version':u'unknown',
      u'os':u'iPhone OS',
      u'properties':{  

      },
   },
   u'data':[  
      {  
         u'session':{  
            u'properties':{  

            }
         },
         u'events':[  
            {  
               u'timestamp':1416848727792,
               u'properties':{  

               },
               u'event_sequence_number':427,
               u'network_type':u'unknown'
            },
         ]
      }
   ],
   u'data_version':u'2.0'
}
```

If I `str()` this json and set it equal to variable a.

Then I perform json.loads(a)

I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/json/__init__.py", line 338, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/json/decoder.py", line 365, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/json/decoder.py", line 381, in raw_decode
    obj, end = self.scan_once(s, idx)
ValueError: Expecting property name: line 1 column 2 (char 1)
```

However if the json did not have unicode representation, `json.loads` works fine. How can I fix this issue?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The premise of the question is mistaken: The input given is not valid JSON.

Use `json.dump()` or `json.dumps()`, as appropriate, to generate the files you're subsequently trying to load.